# Combining vector layers in which the polygon lines have to be 98% similar

Tags: qgis

I have two vector layers, one with multiple polygons overlapping each other (Layer 1).
[image]

The other with small polygons (Layer 2). [image]

Layer 1 also contains some polygons of layer 2. But they are slightly different so most things I tried don't work.

I tried: Vector>Datamanagement tools> Join attributes by location and selecting "equals". Basically I need a tool that does the exact same thing, because I need to combine both attribute tables. But some polygons that are in Layer 2 have slightly different polygon lines. That's because they were drawn over by different persons, instead of copying the existing polygons. The polygons of layer 1 and 2 that are equal(but slightly different) contain different information in the attribute table, thats why i need to combine the two, when the polygons equal eachother for 98%

Down below I added an example. The polygon that equals the one in the second picture needs to be added to the new layer. The most common problem I have is that the polygon on the second picture cuts itself out in the layer below that one. Adding to that is that the two polygons that are equal have slightly different lines. But I still need them to combine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your definition of "98% similarity" needs clarity. It might help to describe what you have tried.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question instead of adding a huge comment which has few of the formatting available and none of the review capabilities

Comment: If anything is unclear let me know!

Comment: I'm still not clear exactly what your ultimate goal is. You've mentioned combining attribute tables. You've also mentioned combining polygons, and adding polygons to new layers. These are all different things. See if you can clean up the question so that your aim is very specific. If it is about combining attribute tables, you need to specify how they differ (same columns but different data, or different columns). IF it is about combining geometries, is it to copy Layer 1 to Layer 2, Layer 2 to Layer 1, both layers to a new layer or something else altogether.